# Joomla 3.9.14 - configuration.php not writable for development website

Tags: php, file-permissions, joomla3.0, web-testing, file-ownership

Using MariaDB10.3, Apache2.4, PHP7.2 on Lubuntu 18.04 (very similar to Ubuntu 18.04)

I want to use my computer offline for designing a website with Joomla. Later, I want to transfer this website to a shared host server. I opened in my browser
localhost/installation
and started the setup of a Joomala website.
I finished the first 3 steps

1. Configuration
2. Database
3. FTP
4. Overview

Now, I hang at step 4. All icons are green, except the "No" icon at the end of the line

**configuration.php Writable No**

Currently the configuration.php is still in the directory:

**/home/tomjones/internet/public_html/installation/model/configuration.php**

```
$ ls -l
```

shows

**-rw-r--r-- 1 tomjones tomjones ... configuration.php**

I identified the owner of the directory

**/home/tomjones/internet/public_html**

as

**www-data**

by opening in a browser the new user.php file with only 1 line code in it:

```
<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>
```

I changed the user:group of configuration.php
from

**tomjones:tomjones** to

**www-data:www-data**

and restarted apache 2 by

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Then I went back from step 4 to 3 in the Joomla installation menu and forward from step 3 to 4.
The red icon 
No
persists (configuration.php Writable No).

[Joomla docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/Cannot_save_Global_Configuration_changes) warns to change the permissions of configuration.php.
Nevertheless, I tried also different permissions:

- 0444 (not writable at all)
- 0644 (original)
- 0664
- 0666
- 0777

for the following 2 variants of ownership (user:group)

- tomjones:tomjones
- www-data:www-data

I always restartet apache2 and changed in the Joomla installation menu from 4 to 3 (FTP) to 4 (overview).
The problem was never solved.
Therefore, I did not press the button
Install
in the Joomla installation menu.

What do you recommend?

Comment: Do you know about [joomla.se] Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 2):

`-rw-r--r--  1 www-data:www-data` should work for the configuration file. I would not expect the file to be writable when tomjones:tomjones was the owner.

I would try running the installation process if the file is at least `0644` and `www-data` owns it.

Also worth double-checking that all the other files are owned by `www-data:www-data`.